# Java: two dimensional array method - calling it in the main method and its complexity

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity, big-o

I haven't yet fully understood what exactly to write in the main method when I have a two dimensional double array method. I want to know what the output of the code is, when `A = {{4.00,3.00}, {2.00,1.00}}` and `B = {{-0.500, 1.500}, {1.000, -2.0000}}`. If we assume, that throwing the exception is a constant complexity `O(1)`, is it right, that the complexity of the following method in Big-O is: `O(1 + aRows * bColumns + aRows * bColumns * aColumns + 1)`? Or is it just `O(aRows * bColumns * aColumns)`?

```
public class Exercise {

public static void main(String[] args){

}

public static double[][] m (double[][] A, double [][] B){

    int aRows = A.length;
    int aColumns = A[0].length;
    int bRows = B.length;
    int bColumns = B[0].length;

    if (aColumns != bRows){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A: Rows: " + aColumns + " did not match B: Columns " + bRows + ".");
    }

    double[][] C = new double[aRows][bColumns];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            C[i][j] = 0.00000;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++ ){
        for (int j = 0; j < bColumns; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < aColumns; k++){
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return C;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for 2D array literals is a bit cumbersome in Java, but it is

```
double[][] a=new double[][]{ new double[]{1.0,2.0},new double[]{0.3,0.4}}
```

As for Big O notation, generally you'd look at the slowest loop or the one that gets slower the fastest, and calculate the amount of iterations of the loop. There is nothing wrong with writing the O notation as a sum of the iteration counts of each consecutive loop, though, although you may want to pay attention to the amount of instructions executed in each loop. However, you want to make the case where an error is thrown a separate case in the O notation, since it skips both loops.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote double[][] a = new double[][]{new double[]{4.00, 3.00}, new double[]{-0.500,1.500}};
        double[][] b = new double[][]{new double[]{-0.500,1.500}, new double[]{1.000, -2.00000}};
        m(a,b); in my main method, but it won't print the outptut. Why is that?

Comment: @TeachMeJava2017 You need to assign it to a variable and write the code that prints the array's contents. You'll want to use `System.out.print()` to print multiple times on the same line (or `System.out.printf()` if you're feeling adventurous), and call `System.out.println()` between rows of the array..

Comment: So I wrote   double[][] x = m(a,b);
        System.out.println(x); but it will only print out the reference and not the actual values.. [[D@7852e922

Comment: @TeachMeJava2017 That's what I meant with having to write the code and use `print`or `printf`: you need to iterate over the array and print the elements individually.